# Why Salesforce naming conventions are like what they are?

Tags: framework, naming-convention

So in salesforce while naming any custom object or any custom filed the spaces between the two words are replaced by an underscore and it add __c in the end.
But why cannot they just remove space and add __c in the end why wasting memory for those extra underscores?

I mean if I name a custom field as Personal Score then in case of of writing the api name as Personal_Score__c why can't they just save it as
PersonalScore__c / PersonalScore_c for more memory management. And what is the idea behind replacing the spaces into one single underscore between two words?

Comment: As a developer, I always change default API names of custom objects and fields to upper camel case, to be consistent with standard ones (such as `OpportunityLineItem.ProductCode`).

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are used as delimiters in both Apex and SOQL so this would not compile:

```
myObject.Personal Score__c = 5;
```

whereas this will:

```
myObject.Personal_Score__c = 5;
```

and if you want to, you can shorten the API name to e.g.:

```
myObject.PersonalScore__c = 5;
```

Automatically replacing the space with an underscore is perhaps an arbitrary choice made by Salesforce designers a long time ago. For people who use all lowercase names it makes sense so e.g.:

```
myObject.personal_score__c = 5;
```

is probably a better result than:

```
myObject.personalscore__c = 5;
```

Memory impacts one way or the other are insignificant.

Comment: why __c why not _c?

Comment: @Samswarup Decision made a long way in the past that if `_` represents a space then `__` represents a prefix or suffix separator. So `xyz_A_c` is not a custom field but `xyz__A__c` is a custom field `A` in the namespace `xyz`.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of space salesforce.com would save is literally nothing, as the object names are stored in a database that presumably uses a CHAR field type for the name, for performance reasons. This means that "HelloWorld__c" and "Hello_World__c" both take up the same amount of space. The "__c" rule allows salesforce.com to introduce new objects with no chance of a naming conflict. The rule about replacing multiple spaces with a single underscore is again related to naming conflict prevention. If I can name an object Account__Share, that would conflict with the standard object (also assuming that the "__c" rule didn't exist). Also note... it's only the default. Many developers prefer to manually edit the object name so that no underscores are present, as this improves developer productivity by not having to type as many underscores.